# Is there a simple CRUD example app using react.js and firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

After what felt like almost 8 years of Rails Development, about a year ago I decided to start working with meteor.js and as of the last month, have begun working with react.js.

I've been through the [React for Beginners](http://www.reactforbeginners.com) course (which I really liked, and learned a lot from) and by way of the course am really interested in [Firebase](http://firebase.io). I believe I am understanding the nature of syncing and using re-base, procs, and states however in searching around for sample apps, I just can't seem to find a basic CRUD app. It seems like there should be a simple example for something like this but I can't seem to find one.

In the case of a sample blog app, I'm looking for a bare-bones app that creates, reads, updates, and deletes data from a collection. Pagination and authentication would be icing on the cake.

I've started coding a prototype, as in the case of the 2 gists below; [App.js](https://gist.github.com/imarichardson/e1f3c9dfe86750d003e1.js) is the container and [AnnoucementsList.js](https://gist.github.com/imarichardson/61511debaedc9130ff6e.js) holds announcements. Just wondering if there are any other examples and if the app has to do CRUD this way.

If anyone can share something you've built or links to a source I'd appreciate it much.

Comment: Have you written any code that uses Firebase yet? Maybe start there. React integration shouldn't be any different than an app without React. Generally whenever you need to hook some data into React you just use a lifecycle hook like `componentDidMount` or `constructor` if you're using `class`

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, I have started. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or just not understanding but I'm using stat sync to edit items. Maybe my mind is not yet conformed to the react way but I feel like this is way too much. As an example here are two gists, App.js (app container) and AnnouncmentsList.js (listing of announcements). Just looking for an example for how to do this kind of thing in a full circle process.

Comment: App:  https://gist.github.com/imarichardson/e1f3c9dfe86750d003e1.js

Comment: Announcements:  https://gist.github.com/imarichardson/61511debaedc9130ff6e.js

Comment: @imarichardson Is the answer I provided below what you are looking for? Could you provide more details if it is not?

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for something like a todo app?https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/tree/master/examples/todoApp

Firebase has a reactfire library that includes information about how to use reactfire as well as links to two examples: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/

This blog post also covers the basics of using react with firebase: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-05-01-using-firebase-with-react.html

Comment: Thanks for checking-in. I've looked at that todo App.The problem is that it doesn't seem to be something I'd do in real life. The complete collection of todos are stored in the state. If, for example, I had a contact manager app with 1000 contacts, each with 20 different fields, I wouldn't want to store all of that in state. I'm just not finding real, business apps that demonstrate this. In meteor I'd publish and subscribe to get specific info, and then have appropriate methods to CRUD contacts. I'm not finding these types of examples with Firebase and React. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @imarichardson Storing 1000 contacts with 20 different fields is childs play in Firebase - it can easily handle 100x that amount of data with dozens (hundreds) of simultaneous connections. I would really suggest walking through the Firebase tutorials and crafting up a small app to get the feel for Firebase. This answer is pretty well on point.

Comment: Not sure if it's clear from my comments or the details under the question, but I am actually doing this. I'm coming from the meteor and rails world there are beginner apps and apps that show a bit more. Sorry if this isn't clear, but I've already seen these. I'm just looking for more detailed business case examples providing the CRUD data I'm looking for.

Comment: the first github link is dead

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same and couldn't find a satisfying answer. 
I've built a really simple CRUD (that is however a real CRUD, not missing the Update feature).

1. Install the official Create React App Bootstrapper: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app
2. Replace the code in App.js with the following
3. update the config part with your details from Firebase Console

Code for App.js:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
    //COPY THE CHUNK FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE IN HERE
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config)

class UpdateableItem extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: props.text,
      amount: (props.amount == null) ? 0 : props.amount,
      currency: (props.currency == null) ? 'DKK' : props.currency
    };
    this.dbItems = firebase.database().ref().child('items');

    this.itemChange = this.itemChange.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdateItem = this.handleUpdateItem.bind(this);
  }

  itemChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  handleUpdateItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.text && this.state.text.trim().length !== 0) {
      this.dbItems.child(this.props.dbkey).update(this.state);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleUpdateItem }>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.dbkey + 'itemname'}>Name</label>
        <input 
          id={this.props.dbkey + 'itemname'}
          onChange={ this.itemChange } 
          value={ this.state.text } 
          name="text"
        />
        <br/>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.dbkey + 'itemamaount'}>Amount</label>
        <input 
          id={this.props.dbkey + 'itemamaount'}
          type="number"
          onChange={ this.itemChange } 
          value={ this.state.amount } 
          name="amount"
        />
        <br/>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.dbkey + 'itemselect'}>Currency</label>
        <select 
          id={this.props.dbkey + 'itemcurrency'}
          value={ this.state.currency }
          onChange={ this.itemChange }
          name="currency"
        >
          <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
        <button>Save</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      newitemtext : ''
    };
    this.dbItems = firebase.database().ref().child('items');

    this.onNewItemChange = this.onNewItemChange.bind(this);
    this.handleNewItemSubmit = this.handleNewItemSubmit.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dbItems.on('value', dataSnapshot => {
      var items = [];

      dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item['.key'] = childSnapshot.key;
        items.push(item);
      });

      this.setState({
        items: items
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dbItems.off();
  }

  handleNewItemSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.newitemtext && this.state.newitemtext.trim().length !== 0) {
      this.dbItems.push({
        text: this.state.newitemtext
      });
      this.setState({
        newitemtext: ''
      });
    }
  }

  onNewItemChange(e) {
    this.setState({newitemtext: e.target.value});
  }

  removeItem(key){
    this.dbItems.child(key).remove();
  }

  render() {
    var _this = this;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>
            App
          </h2>
        </div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(function(item) {
            return ( 
              <li key={ item['.key'] }>
                <UpdateableItem dbkey={item['.key']} text={item.text} currency={item.currency} amount={item.amount} />
                <a onClick={ _this.removeItem.bind(null, item['.key']) } style={{cursor: 'pointer', color: 'red'}}>Delete</a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={ this.handleNewItemSubmit }>
          <input 
            onChange={ this.onNewItemChange } 
            value={ this.state.newitemtext } 
          />
          <button>{ 'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1) }</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a great to-do app I'm looking at. Try opening two windows at this address: https://github.com/dankoknad/todo-firebase

[image]